# REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES - Google Play Console - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

Since an application I have previously published uses the open_file package, the reason for the permission in the title is being asked. I fixed this permission in my new update, but before I throw my new update, I am asked why my live application uses this permission. However, I cannot explain because I have never used this permission. Even if I want to publish the new corrected version in open/closed beta, it still asks me to specify why the released version uses this permission. While assigning the new version to the closed beta, I sent my live application to the policy section explaining the situation, but I was rejected, how can I overcome this problem?

I uploaded the corrected version to the closed beta and sent a text explaining the situation in the existing policy information.